# Triangular domino tiling of an almost regular hexagon

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, tiling, dominoes

### Background

An **almost regular hexagon** is a hexagon where

- all of its internal angles are 120 degrees, and
- pairs of the opposite sides are parallel and have equal lengths (i.e. a [zonogon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonogon)).

The following is an example of an almost regular hexagon, with side lengths 2 (red), 4 (blue), and 3 (yellow).

[image]

A **triangular domino** is a domino made of two unit triangles. A **triangular domino tiling** is a tiling on a shape using triangular dominoes. The following is a possible triangular domino tiling of the above shape (each color represents an *orientation* of each triangular domino):

[image]

### Challenge

Given the lengths of the three sides of an almost regular hexagon, find the number of distinct triangular domino tilings. The three sides will be always positive integers.

### Alternative description

The second image shows that such a tiling can be viewed as an isometric view of stacked unit cubes. Now let's assign three directions to three axes in 3D:

- `x` = down-right / southeast / SE (blue edges in the first image)
- `y` = down-left / southwest / SW (red edges)
- `z` = up / north / N (yellow edges)

Then the stacked unit cubes can be represented as an `x`-by-`y` 2D array, whose items represent the height of the stack at that position. So the above challenge is equivalent to the following:

> Given three positive integers `x`, `y`, and `z`, find the number of `x`-by-`y` arrays whose elements are between 0 and `z` inclusive and all rows and columns are in decreasing order.

It happens that this is one definition of [plane partition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanePartition.html) in the form of \$ PL(x,y,z) \$, and it has a closed-form formula:

$$
PL(x,y,z) = \prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \prod_{k=1}^z \frac{i+j+k-1}{i+j+k-2}
$$

### Scoring and winning criterion

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Note that a submission is valid even if it suffers from integer overflows or floating-point inaccuracies, as long as the underlying algorithm is correct.

### Test cases

```
x,y,z => output
---------------
1,1,1 => 2
1,1,2 => 3
1,2,3 => 10
2,3,1 => 10 (the order of inputs doesn't matter, since it's the same hexagon)
2,3,4 => 490
3,4,2 => 490
3,3,5 => 14112
```

Comment: @LuisMendo If you're referring to the second figure, each color represents an *orientation* of each domino. A domino is a rhombus (i.e. diamond) bounded by solid black edges.

Comment: Of course, they are rhombi, not triangles. My bad. Still, I'd clarify that the colour just indicates orientation for easier viewing of the figure

Comment: Distinct up to what symmetry group?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Symmetry is not considered. For example, 180 degrees rotation of the second image is distinct from the original.

Answer (score 14):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
×/1+1÷1+∘,1⊥¨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQb/D0/XN9Q2PLzdUPtRxwwdw0ddSw@teNS7@X8aUPZRbx9EYVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moKhgpGCMVcaiFQwAQA)

Uses 0 indexing with `⎕IO←0`.

#### Explanation:

```apl
             ⍳     ⍝ Cartesian product of the ranges from 0 to n-1
          1⊥¨      ⍝ Sum of each element (using base 1)
         ,         ⍝ Flattened
        ∘          ⍝ Composed with
  1+1÷1+           ⍝ 1 + 1/(n+1)
×/                 ⍝ And reduced by multiplication
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>38</s> 30 bytes

```perl6
{[*] map 1+1/(*+1),[X+] ^<<@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc7RioMwEAXQ581X3KdWm4BG3YUudulnFKxdpI5V0ESSLGwp/XabVOblDFzuzExm/FqmOzYdDlge1a7G1MyQXCbRjstYVCde41KWx9/n0mmDaBwU2RgP9mGbOzrwspy@b8m55Ul1yWv2XKTwg8MPMhaYBeaemcgDZcq81oRMEbmeoE1LBrrDoOY/Z9Fqsmrr/C/OkRGwg7oSBre1CHHbTISe/pubVvG7rQhtxT5lnuvFdcnF5/tOIWX2Ag)

Based on the formula given in the question

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                            }    # Anonymous code block
                        ^<<@_     # Map each input to the range 0 to n-1
                   [X+]           # Get the cross product of sums
     map          ,               # Map these to
         1+1/(*+1)                # 1+1/(n+1) = (n+2/n+1)
                                  # Which is the formula compensating for the 0 based range
 [*]                              # And reduce by multiplication
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
Œp§_2İ‘P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIJDy@ONjmx41DAj4P/h9kdNayL//4821AHCWB0wbQSmjXSMgTSQBIuDaBMgDSTB8sZAvmksAA)

Uses the altered form of the closed form expression. Takes input as a list `[x,y,z]`.

```
Œp          Cartesian product of the list.
            (Each element, being an integer, is implicitly converted to a range.)
  §         Sum the items of each triplet,
   _2       subtract 2 from each sum,
     İ      take the reciprocal of each lowered sum,
      ‘     increment each reciprocal,
       P    and return the product of the increments reciprocals.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
%/*/'2 1+\:+/!:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs1LV19JXN1Iw1I6x0tZXtOLiKrGqVomurCuySlOosE7Iz7bWSEhLzMyxrrCutC7SjK3lKok2VABCayO9WCjbyNoYyjZSMLY2NABzgEygIiSOibWJJYQHZAP1IHjGCqbWhiaGhkATFfTzy1KL0nLyywH9wicM)

last test fails because of an overflow

uses a 0-indexed version of the formula:

\$PL(x,y,z)=\prod_{i=0}^{x-1}\prod_{j=0}^{y-1}\prod_{k=0}^{z-1}\frac{i+j+k+2}{i+j+k+1}\$

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Array[1+1/(##-2)&,#,1,1##&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@9@xqCixMtpQ21BfQ1lZ10hTTUdZx1DHUFlZLVbtf0BRZl5JtLKCrp1CWrRybKyCmoK@g0J1taGOAgjV6ihAmUZQppGOgjGICaKhCiBMExATREPVGoNFTWtr/wMA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes

```hs
foldr(\r k->k+k/(sum r-2))1.mapM(\n->[1..n])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFNEkAgGADQq3wLixqVobHkBk5QLRqE6UdTXN/nvdNWv4eAbtLo7rAVogt4PvvWd6S@EQofKO1FtHkhOvFZ9UIkQzHaK8EEuVzpgQYcKMkkGw1@qwv2qMjXnH8)

Outputs floats. Thanks to @H.PWiz for 4 bytes using a fold.

Comment: You can get shorter by replacing `product.map` with a `fold`

Comment: @H.PWiz Nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>13</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L.«â€˜OÍz>P
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fR@/Q6sOLHjWtOT3H/3BvlV3A///RxjomOkaxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/H71Dqw8vetS05vQc/8O9VXYB/3X@R0cb6gBhrI4CmGEEYRjpGIMYQAoiBWKYgBhACqLGGChiGhsLAA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the derived formula (inspired by *@JoKing*'s answers):
$$PL(x,y,z) = \prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \prod_{k=1}^z \frac{1}{i+j+k-2}+1$$

```python
L            # Map each value in the (implicit) input-list to an inner [1,v]-ranged list
 .«          # (Right-)reduce these lists by:
   â         #  Taking the cartesian product between two lists
    €˜       # Then flatten each inner list
      O      # Sum each inner list
       Í     # Decrease all by 2
        z    # Take 1/v for each value
         >   # Increase all by 1
          P  # And take the product of that
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: @Grimmy I thought so as well at first, but from the challenge description: "_Note that a submission is valid even if it suffers from integer overflows or floating-point inaccuracies, as long as the underlying algorithm is correct._"

Comment: Whoops, missed that!

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 75

Inputs are passed as a comma-separated list.

```bash
e={1..${1//,/\}+\{1..}}
eval eval echo \\$\[1 *\\\($e-1\\\) /\\\($e-2\\\) ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhLDsIwDET3PsUssmghNEoKK8RJMItAU6UfUQkkWEQ5e3ABW/PsN1f/jKWvaqQSTsk2jUrWGG04b3nVnCm8/IwfbnEBs@KzxYaZKxV2Vm4N8zf3tUvJ9I7DHPAIvsOAEdMR3UKQ6aEGrUatJuqWeygWsrTSCR1akkizck8S6Vv5Dx8)
The last test fails due to integer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>73 65</s>  64 bytes

```javascript
(x,y,z)=>(g=n=>!n||g(n-1)/(s=n%z-~(n/z%y)+n/z/y%x|0)*-~s)(x*y*z)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BDoIwFATQvafABcn/2FpacOGi3IUgEI35NdYY2hCuXrtCAmQWs3jJzKP@1rZ5318fTubWhk4HGJhjHnUFvSZdHWkceyAuUYDVlHo@AQmfOjzFEi4dxhwzPlmEIXOZx9AYsubZnp@mhw4ki0FMhEh0lajDVtWsxUYVK2aV@YojLqZ3uZy5vK496uJ7zwt2@c@XUqrwAw)

#### Commented

```javascript
(x, y, z) => (              // (x, y, z) = input
  g = n =>                  // g is a recursive function taking a counter n
    !n ||                   //   if n = 0, stop recursion and return 1
    g(n - 1) / (            //   otherwise, divide the result of a recursive call by:
      s =                   //     s defined as the sum of:
        n % z               //       k, 0-indexed: n mod z
        - ~(n / z % y)      //       j, 1-indexed: floor((n / z) mod y) + 1
        + n / z / y % x | 0 //       i, 0-indexed: floor((n / z / y) mod x)
    )                       //   
    * -~s                   //   and multiply by s + 1
)(x * y * z)                // initial call to g with n = x * y * z
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 25 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Bubbler!

```
[:*/1+1%1+1#.&>[:,@{i.&.>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYAXEunoKzkE@bv@jrbT0DbUNVYFYWU/NLtpKx6E6U09Nz@6/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQloxV2pyRr5CmpqdgiEIWoNIIyBppGBsDcRAERBpYg3EQHFjINtU4T8A)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
[:*/[:(1+1%1++/)@>[:,@{<@i."0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYg7CoAwFAT7nGIR/EZi4qd5Uck9UopBbSwsxbPHF5YZlrlieBYFDYKOnprOU2WkyY2UXe1WT617Z3eqTMdaZAplWFSJFh8hPELs23EjFCtMmk3u2T0Gy3BJHi3DfeA/If4)

A [J](http://jsoftware.com/) port of [@JoKing's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196081/75681) (don't forget to upvote it), but twice as long. I'll try to golf it...

Comment: [25 bytes.](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYAXEunoKzkE@bv@jrbT0DbUNVYFYWU/NLtpKx6E6U09Nz@6/JpeSnoJ6mq2euoKOQloxV2pyRr5CmpqdgiEIWoNIIyBppGBsDcRAERBpYg3EQHFjINtU4T8A)

Comment: @Bubbler Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
*/@,@(1+%)1++/&i./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCoMwEATQ@37FULBWYxMnSQ8NCNKCJ@mhH6Ho/9/jamCHx@zunm8W9YIhoUaHHknztPj@5ym3buzGB03V0Bh336zLjaxDWjKxgqAU/aVHEK8G3RejBDXqPVz9Jb@PPf/A/pz4LmEk/QE)

Takes `z` on its left and `x y` on the right.

Uses [modified formula by Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196070/triangular-domino-tiling-of-an-almost-regular-hexagon#comment466589_196089):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \frac{i+j+z-1}{i+j-1} &= \prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \left(1 + \frac{z}{i+j-1}\right) \\
&= \prod_{i=0}^{x-1} \prod_{j=0}^{y-1} \left(1 + \frac{z}{i+j+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$

#### How it works

```
*/@,@(1+%)1++/&i./  NB. Left =: z, Right =: x y
                 /  NB. Reduce over x y...
              &i.   NB.   Apply range (n -> 0..n-1) to each item and
            +/      NB.   Outer product by addition
          1+        NB. Increment each, so that each cell has i+j+1
    @(1+%)          NB. Compute 1+z/(i+j+1) for each i and j
*/@,                NB. Flatten the matrix and compute the product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85</s> 75 bytes

```ruby
->x,y,z{w=->t{(0...x*y*z).map{|r|r%x+(r/=x)%y+r/y+t}.reduce &:*};w[2]/w[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxJDoMgAIXhfU9B0tgoIsjQRdvARYiLDrozMUQDOJydkg5q3u5L3m@Ghw@NDIVyyKNxsrJQ/ZSWGGMHPRwz3N67aTazSVyeGiJdlvjcEJ/3Czb1a3jW4HSFy81qVhGrabWEDjSaorgKHAkBUgF2@Btbjf@MIb4aLT8YaXfeoVhRXL4abdfclKPzFhCUsvAG)

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>81, 78</s> 70 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Peter Taylor

```
procedure f(x,y,z)
p:=1&p*:=(1+z/(seq()\x+seq()\y-1.))&\u
return p
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc69DoMgEADgWZ4CFwOVtkHbxcQnUYZGz4ShSK/Sii9v0Q5yN1y@3E9Od6NZV4tjB71DoAObhRcLJ7aqZWZPVc1kvlzZG16Mt3P@r/4sL5xnrSMIk0NDLQHTR2eeD20YJzQEfAA9/aKegA1p2jRShFSCJMnW3lnELER5MCAe3ng7GBDvlqF7V4rvz/wA)

Comment: Does this benefit from telescoping one product to $$\prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \frac{i+j+z-1}{i+j-1} = \prod_{i=1}^x \prod_{j=1}^y \left(1 + \frac{z}{i+j-1}\right)$$?

Comment: Answer: yes, 8-char reduction if the second line is changed to `p:=1&p*:=(1+z/(seq()\x+seq()\y-1.))&\u`

Comment: @Peter Taylor That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>79</s> 62 bytes

Based on @galen-ivanov's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196089/32604).

-17 bytes thanks to Jo King and xnor.

```python
lambda x,y,z,t=1:[t:=t+t*z/(i%x-~i//x)for i in range(x*y)][-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxCsMgGATgvU/hUvBPDWJsIQR8kjSDIbUVWiPyD5qhr27tptz0cXc@4Wt3cvQhG3XPb/1ZN00iS@xgqMQ046Twgt3BqT3H/ms5j2D2QCyxjgTtng8auwTL3Isl@2AdUkMFKwE41R4aD0xWLmr2f18rFzV/WfobQP4B)

Comment: [63 bytes](https://tio.run/##VctBDsIgFATQvadgY8KvGNKiSdOEk1gXmIqS6C8hfwFd9OqIO8isXmbGJ3qvqEYfstVz/pjvYzEsiiQ2QbqfbjRpOlG3Se6O8bw7KSPYNTDHHLJg8PXksUtwN7gwyj44JG55L0oADrWHxoNQlYua/d@XykXNX5X@CpB/), though with a couple of minor rounding errors

Comment: You can also do `[-1]` rather than `and t` to extract what `t` ends p as.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦＮＦηＦθ⊞υ⊕⁺λ⁺κιＩ÷Π⊕υΠυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxDsMgDEX3nMKjLdGl7ZaxXbJUXIECFaiENIBzfUpRpMbL139fz9qppBcVap3ih8uD56dNuNI4HLtr/bUkwCMkgs7cniuB5OyQBUxRJzvbWKxBGThjENDzLcBTu3GQyceCN5VLe1rufvPGokyLYf0jf5@JmrwP3OVaz3CBaz1t4Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Uses the 0-indexed version of the given formula.

```
ＮθＮηＦＮＦηＦθ
```

Input the three dimensions and loop over the implicit ranges.

```
⊞υ⊕⁺λ⁺κι
```

Take each incremented sum and save it in a list, thus flattening the Cartesian product.

```
Ｉ÷Π⊕υΠυ
```

Divide the product of the incremented list by the product of the list and cast to string for implicit print.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
mo rï Ëc rÄ pJ ÄÃ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bW8gcu8gy2MgcsQgcEogxMPX&input=W1sxLDIsM10sWzIsMyw0XV0KLW0)

input as array

```
mo rï               // cartesian product [0,n)
      Ëc            // flatten each triplet
         rÄ         // reduce with initial value of 1 ( -2 +3=>triplets 0 to 1
            pJ      // raised -1
               Ä    // +1
                Ã×  // reduce by multiplication

Implicit output, -m flag to run the program for each input
```